# council execution giving bad origin error?

Tags: substrate-node, blockchain, council, motion, badorigin

I am using substrate blockchain which is on `polkadot-v0.9.36`  . I have made  proposal through council which is of `balance.forcetransfer`, and did majority voting in `aye`.After completion , when I close the  proposal motion  it is giving  `bad origin error`. Can  you please tell why is it happening like this .

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

The `force_transfer` extrinsic requires to be called by the `Root` origin ([ref](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/bc5005217a8c2e7c95b9011c96d7e619879b1200/substrate/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L575)). The `Collective` pallet doesn't have this authority ([democracy pallet has](https://github.com/RGafiyatullin/substrate/blob/4d45aca38d7799bab2c85d45aee1ab1dd22d7b1d/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L1682-L1686)). The `Collective` pallet can be used to configure a pallet to only allow members of some collective to issue calls.

Comment: if i have  to use collective pallet to execute any extrinsic ,how i can use it?

Comment: You are doing it the right way, however you can't dispatch an extrinsic (through the `collectives` pallet) that requires the to be called by the `Root` origin. You'll need the `sudo` or `democracy` pallet for that.